# Prestashop shows diffrent price admin - store

Tags: prestashop, rounding, price

prestashop shows prices correctly on admin but; on store it shows down rounded price.

for ex: 
**on admin:** price is 1.498 (tax incl) || **on store:** price is 1

or

**on admin:** price is 0.5 (tax incl) || **on store:** price is 0

```
<div class="current-price">
    <span itemprop="price" content="1.5">1,00</span>
</div>
```

focus on the content and clear value please, **1.5** and **1**.

i tried to change round mode on admin options but the result was not changed. i also tried to modify classes/product.php round mode to round($price,2), but it did not work.

version 1.7, theme, default

Answer (score 0):

These setting can be found in your prestashop back-office.

Go to:
Shop Parameters -> General

You will find there the options "Round Mode" & "Round Type".
Change the value to your requirements

Comment: As I wrote above, I tried it but it did not worked me.

Answer (score 0):

**I've solved this issue by replacing** PS vendor, classes, tool with the same version folders. Maybe someone had changed some part of core PS.

Anyway, round mode is working as default option.